# Angular 404 handling with remote validation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular app that handles 404s via an interceptor.  Specifically:

```
angular.module('app')
  .provider('AppInterceptor', function() {
    this.$get = function($q, $rootScope) {
      return {
        'responseError': function(error) {
          if (error.status === 401) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('unauthorized', error);
          } else if (error.status === 404) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('notFound', error);
          }

          return $q.reject(error);
        }
      };
    };
  });
```

I then listen for this event with:

```
angular.module('app')
  .run(function($rootScope, $state){
    $rootScope.$on('notFound', function(error) {
      $state.go('http404');  // ui-router state change
    });
  });
```

This works great.  However, I have a registration page that relies on 404 errors via a remote validator directive to check if a selected username is already taken.  The remote validator validates the username field by GETing a user record.  Thus, when a user selects a valid username that isn't already taken, the remote validator generates a 404 and, unfortunately, triggers the not found state.

How can I get these two features to live peacefully with each other?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by having my controller that uses the remote validator listen for `$stateChangeStart` events.  I used `preventDefault()` when the toState was my `http404` state.